# Loading multiple gltf files in Three.js that should become hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, three.js

js knowing people,
Below you can see my very first code of JavaScript. I would like to build a website with four different rotating gltf models. Each of them should be a hyperlink. So far I managed somehow to load two of them and let them rotate in the live server. But I'm stuck with this error 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: duck is undefined'.
How can I solve this problem? And how can I create the links?
I'm very thankful for your help.

```
// variables for setup
let container;
let camera;
let renderer;
let scene;
let box;
let duck;
let controls;

function init(){
    container = document.querySelector('.scene');

    //create scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const fov = 10;
    const aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
    const near = 0.1;
    const far = 900;

    // camera setup
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
    camera.position.set(0, 30, 1);


    const ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 3);
    scene.add(ambient);


    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    light.position.set(10,10,30);
    scene.add(light);
    

    //renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
    renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

   
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls (camera, renderer.domElement);
    
    //load model
    let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    
    loader.load('./3d/duck.gltf', function(gltf){
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
        duck = gltf.scene.children[0];
        duck.position.set(0,0,0);
        animate();
    })

    loader.load('./3d/cube.gltf', function(gltf){
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
        box = gltf.scene.children[0];
        box.position.set(-2,0,0);
        animate();
    })

    
}

function animate(){
    controls.update();
    duck.rotation.x += 0.01
    box.rotation.y += 0.01
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}


init();


function onWindowResize () {
    camera.aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
}

    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs at `duck.rotation.x += 0.01`. Since `loader.load` function is asynchronous, the line `duck = gltf.scene.children[0];` is not called before the first execution of `animate()`. Consequently, `duck` variable is undefined. You could avoid it with

```
if(duck) {
  duck.rotation.x += 0.01
}
```

**Regarding hyperlink:**
There is no concept of links in the three.js scene.
Anchor tags are only available in the DOM and it's not a standard element available in WebGL.
You will need to write some code to handle mouse events, click and open the corresponding URL.
The process goes as below:

- Listen to mouse move events and change cursor if the element being hovered on is clickable
- Listen to mouse click and navigate to the link corresponding to the clicked element
- Both of these require projecting a ray from the mouse pointer and checking intersections with the mesh

The three.js documentation is quite clear about the raycaster and intersections with mesh
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster

**Demo:**
https://codepen.io/cdeep/pen/JjyjEdV